# Why background disappears in Internet Explorer

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4

I have built a Joomla website (http://www.apnae.org) that looks good on Chrome/Firefox but its background disappears on Explorer. Can anyone help on solving it? 
Thanks!

Dani

Comment: This might explain it: http://imgur.com/PDeMiPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem being is that you're using `rgba` for your background which is **not** supported by IE8. You need to add a fallback in your CSS to cater for it, like so:

```
#wrapper > div.inner {
    background: rgb(154, 179, 255);
    background: rgba(154, 179, 255, 0.75);
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Replace the current code you have in the following file on line **213** with the above code:

```
templates/apnae/css/template.css
```

You will also need to add a fallback for the sidebar background on line **436** like so:

```
#left > div.inner {
    background: rgb(77, 121, 255);
    background: rgba(77, 121, 255, 0.5);
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks lodder, you are of great help (again). There is a problem. The left sidebar background is gone.

Comment: @DaniValverde - This is due to the code you have on line **65** of the CSS file....remove it

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see the site works fine in IE 9+, but in IE 8 the light blue background behind the content seems to disappear. It's not actually gone, but the image background is placed above it.

(I only tested this in IE11 by emulating IE8, so it might not be acurate)

It seems to have something to do with the use of **[pie.htc](http://css3pie.com/)**. Try removing the following from your template and see if it makes any difference:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css">
#wrapper > div.inner,#nav1 > div.inner,#left > div.inner,#center > div.inner,#content > div.inner { behavior: url(/templates/apnae/pie.htc) }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

(Note that IE8 don't support transparent backgrounds using RGBA).